# pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: can anyone help me

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
import pymysql


f = open('C:\\Users\Allen\Desktop\html style.txt', 'rb')
array = []
for i in f.readlines():
    array.append(i.decode('utf8'))
str1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in array)

conn = pymysql.connect(user='root', host='localhost', password='cwl19940125', database='news', charset='utf8')
mycursor = conn.cursor()
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES ("%s");' % str1
mycursor.execute(sql_insert)
conn.commit()
mycursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Error

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"\ufeff\t<section class="_135editor" data-tools="135编辑器" data-id="85433" style\' at line 1')
```

> i print(sql_insert) to let you see it clear

```
    INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES "<section class="_135editor" data-tools="135编辑器" data-id="85433" style="position: relative;">

    <section class="135brush" data-style="color: inherit; box-sizing: border-box;line-height: 2em; text-align: center;" style="color: inherit; border-color: rgb(216, 40, 33); box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">


          </section>
</section>";
```

> i add the str and i can't find where syntax is . so i need your help ,can someone to help me?

Comment: possibly you have problems with single/double quotes, in your `sql_insert`. if possible `print(sql_insert)`  and add results.

Comment: i just add results

Comment: @ marmeladze i add it now

Comment: as i guess, double quotes terminates your query. you need to escape them. let me figure out how and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES ("%s");' % str1
```

to

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES ('%s');' % str1
                                               ^^  ^^
```

be aware of single quotes here.

```
>>> qry = """insert into posts(title, body) values('lorem ipsum', '%s')""" %sql
>>> print(qry)
insert into posts(title, body) values('lorem ipsum', '<section class="_135editor" data-tools="135" data-id="85433" style="position: relative;">
    <section class="135brush" data-style="color: inherit; box-sizing: border-box;line-height: 2em; text-align: center;" style="color: inherit; border-color: rgb(216, 40, 33); box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
```

Comment: i just try your way ,but i face the new question.pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF\\x09<s...' for column 'content' at row 1")

Comment: this is an encoding problem. try to remove/replace those japanese/chinese characters or add appropriate encoding for it.

Comment: it can't be replace i just to find other way to encoding it. thankyou

Comment: hey, wait a minute. python3 has a built-in support for utf-8. what is your version?

Comment: i solve the problem, change the utf-8 to utf-8-sig.and then also change the content of mysql into utf8. thank you at all!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using string interpolation. Instead,

```
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES (%s);'
mycursor.execute(sql_insert, str1)
```